# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Exception occurred rendering view

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

I have attribute DiscriminatorValue in my entity as transient, only purpose of which is to access later in my jsp page, but jsp can't render it throwing **java.lang.IllegalStateException: Exception occurred rendering view**, I am using tiles FYI. Thanks in advance

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("YesNo")
public class Child extends Parent{ // parent entity has inheritance strategy
    .....

    DiscriminatorValue type; //want to access this variable in spring form

    @Transient
    public String getDiscriminatorValue(){
        type= this.getClass().getAnnotation( DiscriminatorValue.class );
        return type == null ? null : type.value();
    }
}

//somewhere in jsp i have,
 ${child.type}
```

Comment: what is this val? please provide us enough info to sort out the problem.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, it should have been type instead(edited now)

Comment: I tried to replicate your issue I am getting the following exception Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: javax.persistence.DiscriminatorValue,

Comment: That is why i have kept that transient :)

Answer (score 0):

Make the following changes to your class.

```
@Transient
String type; //want to access this variable in spring form

public String getDiscriminatorValue(){
     DiscriminatorValue type = this.getClass().getAnnotation( DiscriminatorValue.class );
        return type == null ? null : type.value();
    }
```

Or you can have your discriminator as a read-only property.

In your parent class add define DiscriminatorColumn

```
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "Dtype", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)

 @Column(name = "Dtype", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String type;
```

//getters and setters for type